# Saving Data into Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

**Background**

I need to scrape data as I do not have direct access to the source data. This is an approved activity within my company.

I am not allowed to post any portion of the html; however, since I have verified the scraping portion of the code, that should not be needed.

**I have written a VBA Macro that:**

- Opens an Internet Explorer window
- Navigates to an Intranet website
- Loads a website filed with the contents of a cell within one worksheet
- Processes to get to a customer record
- Looks for specific website object IDs
- Saves the values from the specific IDs to a 2nd worksheet in the same workbook
- Frees up memory
- Exits

**The issue:**

- The data will not save into the worksheet.

**What I've Tried:**

- Creating a new output worksheet
- Using an existing output worksheet
- Using Save, Activate and Select commands on the workbook
- Referencing the worksheet by:

  - Code name
  - Sheet name
  - Index
- Exhaustive trial and error along with an equivalent amount of research

**The Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetxyzData()

Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim startRange As Range
Dim NoteFound As Boolean
Dim ContactFound As Boolean
Dim itm As Object

'Create the IE Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Set the position and size attributes of the IE Object
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600

'Set the visibility of the IE Object
objIE.Visible = True

'Check to see if there was an error with the website
On Error Resume Next
objIE.navigate ("http://xyz/xyz_Individual/Applications/xyz/SearchMain.aspx/")

'Wait until the website is ready to begin along with error checking
Do While objIE.Busy
   DoEvents

   'Check to see if there was an error loading the website
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      objIE.Quit
      Set objIE = Nothing
      GoTo Program_Exit
   End If

   'Wait until the website is ready to begin
   Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to Website..."
   DoEvents
Loop

'Set the Row Number to 1 since there is a header row
rowCount = 1

'Set the data entry into Excel in the First Column and row
startRange = "A1"

'Continue to loop through the Excel data until a blank entry is found in the ID Number column
Do While Sheet5.Range("K" & rowCount) <> ""

   'Populate the Prospect ID Number in the search box with value in cell "K + Counter"
   objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00$txtProspectid").innerText = _
         "0" & Sheet5.Range("K" & rowCount).Value

   'Click the search button
   objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_btnsearch").Click

   'Wait until the website is ready to begin along with error checking
   Do While objIE.Busy
      Application.StatusBar = "Downloading information, Please wait..."
      DoEvents
   Loop

   'Check to see if this is the first customer and click the appropriate Prospect hyperlink
   If rowCount = 1 Then
      objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_GrdExtract_ctl03_btnsel").Click
   Else
      objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_GrdMember_ctl03_lnkProspectID").Click
   End If

   'Wait until the website is ready to begin
   Do While objIE.Busy
      Application.StatusBar = "Downloading information, Please wait..."
      DoEvents
   Loop

'Set table type indicators to know when we are processing the 1st data field in each
   NoteFound = False
   ContactFound = False

'Get the data fields for PII, Contacts and Notes based on the common portion of ID name
   With Sheets("MWData")
      For Each itm In objIE.document.all
         'If it is not a PII, Contact or Note field, then skip it
         If itm.ID Like "*ctl00_CPH1_tabcontbottom_tabpnlContact_grdContact*" Or _
            itm.ID Like "*ctl00_CPH1_tabcontbottom_tabpnlNotes_GrdUserNotes*" Or _
            itm.ID Like "*ctl00_CPH1_tabconttop_TabpnlPI_txt*" Then

            'Write itm.Value to screen if it is not blank
            If itm.Value <> "" Then
               MsgBox itm.Value
            End If

            ' Check to see if it is the first Contact field for the customer, if so save the
            ' column number the last contact field holds and then increment the rowCounter to store
            ' the first field of the Note fields.
            If itm.ID Like "*ctl00_CPH1_tabcontbottom_tabpnlContact_grdContact*" Then
               'If this is the first Contact field then we want to save the the current colCount
               If ContactFound = False Then
                  .Range(colCount & rowCount) = "ContactStart = " & colCount
                  colCount = rowCount + 1
                  ContactFound = True
               End If
            End If
            ' Check to see if it is the first Note field for the customer, if so save the
            ' column number the last note field holds
            If itm.ID Like "*ctl00_CPH1_tabcontbottom_tabpnlNotes_GrdUserNotes*" Then
               'If this is the first Note field then we want to save the the current colCount
               If NoteFound = False Then
                  .Range(colCount & rowCount) = "NoteStart = " & colCount
                  colCount = rowCount + 1
                  NoteFound = True
               End If
            End If

            ' Store the fields value in the next available column on the same row
            Sheets("MWData").Range(colCount & rowCount) = itm.Value
            'Increment the column counter to the next to prepare to write the next field
            colCount = colCount + 1

         End If

      Next itm
   End With

'Increment the row counter and set the column counter back to 1
rowCount = rowCount + 1
colCount = 1

'Loop back to get the next customer entry
Loop

Application.StatusBar = "Download Complete....."

'Exit the program if there was an error retrieving the website
Program_Exit:

'Clean up system resources before ending the program
objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Put `On Error Goto 0` right after the "DoEvents" loop, to cancel the `On Error Resume Next` - does your code run without any errors ?

Comment: This isn't the source of your error but the code comment says "and then increment the rowCounter" whereas the code says `colCount = rowCount + 1` which looks to be incorrect

Comment: @barrowc - thanks for the great catch.  I've been trying to figure out my issue for over a week before asking and let that slip past me in all of my tweaking.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I haven't had issues with errors.  The code seems to run as intended except for writing the data to the worksheet like I need it to.  I've used MsgBox statements to verify I am getting the data from the website tables that I need.

Answer (score 2):

You use this `.Range(colCount & rowCount)` several times in your code :

`.Range(colCount & rowCount) = "ContactStart = " & colCount`

`.Range(colCount & rowCount) = "NoteStart = " & colCount`

`Sheets("MWData").Range(colCount & rowCount) = itm.Value`

However `colCount` and `rowCount` are integers so this won't work e.g. you will have `Range(12)` where `colCount = 1` and `rowCount = 2`.

You can use the `Cells` collection of the `Worksheet` like this but not the `Range` object, e.g.

`Sheets("MWData").Cells(rowCount, colCount) = itm.Value`

Comment: Thanks.  This is my first experience trying to scrape data and write to an Excel worksheet.  I will give this a try when I get to work in the morning and let you know if this fixes my issue.  I really appreciate your help!